# MYSQL DB SELECT WITH MIN COUNT

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sql-order-by, min

I got a dataset as a table it looks something like this :

```
###################################
UID    |TID     |MID     |RESULT  |
1      |1       |1       |1       |
2      |1       |1       |2       |
3      |1       |1       |3       |
4      |2       |1       |4       |
5      |2       |1       |5       |
6      |2       |1       |6       |
1      |1       |2       |6       |
2      |1       |2       |5       |
3      |1       |2       |4       |
4      |2       |2       |3       |
5      |2       |2       |2       |
6      |2       |2       |1       |
1      |1       |3       |2       |
2      |1       |3       |4       |
3      |1       |3       |6       |
4      |2       |3       |5       |
5      |2       |3       |3       |
6      |2       |3       |1       |
```

I now want to have the minimum amount of each row, grouped by TID and MID

If I do something like this:

```
SELECT UID, TID, MID, RESULT  
FROM matches 
WHERE matches.id = '$ID'  
ORDER BY TID, MID, RESULT
```

I get the things ordered in the right way. Like this:

```
###################################
UID    |TID     |MID     |RESULT  |
1      |1       |1       |1       |
2      |1       |1       |2       |
3      |1       |1       |3       |

3      |1       |2       |4       |
2      |1       |2       |5       |
1      |1       |2       |6       |

1      |1       |3       |2       |
2      |1       |3       |4       |
3      |1       |3       |6       |

4      |2       |1       |4       |
5      |2       |1       |5       |
6      |2       |1       |6       |

6      |2       |2       |1       |
5      |2       |2       |2       |
4      |2       |2       |3       |

6      |2       |3       |1       |
5      |2       |3       |3       |
4      |2       |3       |5       |
```

And I now just want to have the first row of each block. To count how often each UID is best in each block.

I don't know how to get it without doing many loop in php. If I  do GROUP BY TID, MID with MIN(RESULT) it seams a bit random which UID is coming out.

**SOLUTION**:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS AMOUNT, t1.UID AS UID, t1.TID AS TID, t1.MID AS MID, t1.RESULT AS result
  FROM
  (
    SELECT um.user_id AS UID, um.team_id AS TID, um.match_id AS MID, um.q_result AS RESULT
    FROM user_matches um JOIN league_matches lm
    WHERE um.match_id = lm.id
    AND lm.league_subseason_id = '135'
    ORDER BY TID, MID
  ) t1
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT um.user_id AS UID, um.team_id AS TID, um.match_id AS MID, min(um.q_result) AS min_result
    FROM user_matches um JOIN league_matches lm
    WHERE um.match_id = lm.id
    AND lm.league_subseason_id = '135'
    GROUP BY TID, MID
  ) t2 ON t2.TID = t1.TID AND t2.MID = t1.MID AND t2.min_result = t1.result
 GROUP BY t1.UID ORDER BY AMOUNT DESC
```

Comment: `select distinct`and the rest of your code, should do the job.

Comment: just SELECT DISTINCT and then changing nothing doesn't change anything. :(

Comment: What would you like to happen if you get draws - or don't you care? or will it never happen?

Comment: Draws can't happen. There is always one with the lowest Result.

Comment: This is a very common question. The `SQL select only rows with max value on a column` question (2nd duplicate link) provides several, lot more detailed description how you can achieve the same question for maximum values. If you understand the logic from those answers, then those can be easily adapted for minimum values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use subquery with the min for column result group by TID and MID

```
  SELECT UID, TID, MID, RESULT  
  FROM matches  m 
  inner join (
    select TID, MID, min(result) min_result
    from matches 
    group by TID, MID 
  ) t on t.TID = m.TID and t.MID = m.MID and t.min_result = m.result
```

Looking to your code and sample you have a wrong user_id in subselect, you have not group by but order by so i think you should change your code this way

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS AMOUNT, t1.UID AS UID, t1.TID AS TID, t1.MID AS MID, t1.RESULT AS result
  FROM
  (
    SELECT um.user_id AS UID, um.team_id AS TID, um.match_id AS MID, um.q_result AS RESULT
    FROM user_matches um JOIN league_matches lm
    WHERE um.match_id = lm.id
    AND lm.league_subseason_id = '135'
    ORDER BY TID, MID
  ) t1
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT um.user_id AS UID, um.team_id AS TID, um.match_id AS MID, min(um.q_result) AS min_result
    FROM user_matches um JOIN league_matches lm
    WHERE um.match_id = lm.id
    AND lm.league_subseason_id = '135'
    GROUP BY TID, MID
  ) t2 ON t2.TID = t1.TID AND t2.MID = t1.MID AND t2.min_result = t1.result
 GROUP BY t1.UID ORDER BY AMOUNT DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The thing is just a bit more complicated. I tried to adopt it but don't get it.

Comment: @freak228  answer  updated .. with a suggestion ..let me know

Comment: still doesn't work. First there was a problem in the last ORDER BY section (so i changed it to: ORDER BY UID, TID, MID) then the error disappeared. Now it says RESULT is unknown in ON clause.

Comment: asnwer  udpated ..

Comment: Still doesn't work, I think i'll just try it with a loop. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Updated your answer! It works now! THANKS!

Comment: Ok  ..many thanks  ..  you too